# I want to know if it's good for SEO

Tags: wp-admin

I locked the file (wp-admin) from the server

Google Crawler Error
in Address

http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Do you have to lock out?

Due to the cybercrime on the site, I want to keep the site locked

please guide me

Answer (score 1):

The `/wp-admin/ajax.php` file should **not** be locked - it is used to power all AJAX functionality on the site.

Your [`robots.txt`](http://new-song.ir/robots.txt) file specifically instructs search engine spiders (like Google) to allow access to `/wp-admin/ajax.php`:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Sitemap: http://example.com/sitemap.xml
```

Either remove the `Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` and keep `/wp-admin/` locked (effectively disabling all AJAX functionality on your site) or - better solution - unlock `/wp-admin/` and use the [WordFence Security](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/) plugin.